# Why do we use double dash in "git checkout -- ."?

Tags: git

I thought the line

```
git checkout .
```

can revert all changes in the current directory and subdirectory for the local working copy.  But I also see this popular form:

```
git checkout -- .
```

so if `--` [(the double dash or also called "bare double dash") is to signal the end of command options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean), then why is it needed in the above case? The `.` can never be an option so there shouldn't be any confusion.

Answer (score 20):

It's meant to be to resolve ambiguity.

For example, if you had a branch named `bob` (which would checkout that branch) and a folder named `bob` (which would revert that folder).

Comment: so you mean `--` is also to signal the end of branch name (and does it signal the end of anything else?).  So for `git checkout .` it really doesn't need the `--`?

Comment: @動靜能量 for the case of `git checkout .`, there is no ambiguity if there is no branch named `.` (is naming a branch `.` even allowed in git? I'm not sure). Therefore, using `--` in `git checkout -- .` is purely optional. I usually use `--` anyways, out of habit.

Comment: so it looks like in UNIX, `--` is to signal the end of command options.  While in `git`, `--` can signal the end of what's first commonly expected.  So `git checkout -- main.c` means: I am indicating that there is no branch name explicitly by typing in `--`

Comment: I never do `-- .`, it's pointless in that regard (unless of course it's possible and you're silly enough to name a branch `.`).

Comment: `.` is not a valid branch name in git. You can verify this by typing `git checkout -b .` in any git repository.

Comment: For reverting changes, there is alternate in git v2.23.0. git restore .